# How to create a stored procedure containing a DELIMITER in PHP with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, delimiter

In my model I defined some procedures. The code (generated by MySQL Workbench) contains `DELIMITER` definitions, so the procedures look like:

```
-- schema
CREATE DATABASE ...
CREATE TABLE foo ...
-- procedures
DELIMITER $$
...
  BEGIN
    DECLARE ... ;
    OPEN ... ;
    SET ... ;
    ... ;
  END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now I need to "import" the SQL to the database via [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). I tried to pass it as input for the [`PDO#exec(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php), but noticed, that the execution stops on the line of the first `DELIMITER` definition.

I don't want remove the `DELIMITER` statements. So the the SQL code should remain the same.

**How to use PDO to execute SQL code containing `DELIMITER` statements?**

Answer (score 9):

From comments:

> I don't want remove the `DELIMITER` statements. And actually I want to get it working without to execute every statement manually

That's not how it works.

To understand why, you need to understand how the `mysql` CLI -- and any other program that can read and execute a dump file like this -- actually handles it.

`DELIMITER` is not something the server understands.

`DELIMITER` is used to tell the **client-side parser** what the current statement delimiter should be, so that the client-side parser can correctly split the statements and deliver one at a time to the server for execution.

From the docs.  Note carefully that `mysql`, every time it is used here, refers to the `mysql` *client utility* -- not the server.

> If you use the `mysql` client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, `mysql` itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you must redefine the delimiter temporarily to cause `mysql` to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.

> To redefine the `mysql` delimiter, use the `delimiter` command. [...] The delimiter is changed to `//` to enable the entire definition to be passed to the server as a single statement, and then restored to `;` before invoking the procedure. This enables the `;` delimiter used in the procedure body to be passed through to the server rather than being interpreted by `mysql` itself.

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html

So, to handle such a file, you need a client-side parser that does the same thing `mysql` does... and here, the code you are writing **is** (needs to be) the client-side statement parser.  So you are the one that needs to write the logic to handle the delimiter.

To do what you want, you have to interpret the `DELIMITER` statements, use them to keep track of the current statement delimiter, but do not send them to the server.

Then, you have to read through the input one line at a time, buffering what you've read, until you find the specified delimiter at the end of the line, and send the resulting statement to the server -- *excluding* the actual statement delimiter from what you send... so, for example, you would not send the ending `$$` after the procedure body (unless the current statement delimiter is `;`, which you can either send or not send -- the server doesn't care.)  Then empty the buffer and start reading again until you see another instance of a delimiter (and send the statement to the server) or match a `DELIMITER` statement and set your code's current delimiter variable to match it so that you correctly identify the end of the next statement.

Comment: Very good explaination. That's also answer my question on how I implemented this before. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Delimiters is a thing that you don't need with PDO. You can just run your queries as is

```
$pdo->query("CREATE DATABASE ...");
$pdo->query("CREATE TABLE foo ...");
$pdo->query("BEGIN
    DECLARE ... ;
    OPEN ... ;
    SET ... ;
    ... ;
  END");
```

as simple as that

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, it would work. And even `$pdo->exec($myBugSqlStatementWithoutSelimiterStatements)` would work. But as I said in my answer, I don't want remove the `DELIMITER` statements. And actually I wnat to get it working without to execute every statement manually.

Comment: Thanks for examples, Last example helped me, was trying to create a procedure, didn't realize I don't need to worry about `delimiter`.

Answer (score -2):

I met same problem with you when I tried with PostgreSQL. The problem seems PDO just allow you execute 1 query 1 time. As mentioned: `PDO::exec() executes an SQL statement in a single function call, returning the number of rows affected by the statement`. In [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

Could you try this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Or with `mysqli`: `multi_query`. [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Here my whole class: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f0528fda6d7bd097c3199f1f3c019805a163ae3a

Comment: he is asking regarding PDO, not mysqli

Comment: Actually I would be also happy, if it works with MySQLi. Anyway I don't see a reason to downvote the question!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just tried it with `MySQLi#multi_query(...)`, but the result is the same -- the code after `DELIMITER` is ignored. If you still have your solution for PostgreSQL, could you please post its code. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the update! Just tried out `$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql); $statement->execute();`. But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, it only works when I tried to explode the with the sign: `--DELIMITER` that I manually use to detect. Your case maybe `-- procedures`

Comment: Even if it's not work, and you can figure out the way, please update it here also. Thank you

Comment: Thank you again for trying help! You told about `multi_query(...)`. But in your solution you don't use it. But I think, I got the Idea: Remove the comments, extract the SQL code statement by statement, `prepare` every one, and execute them in a loop. I want to find a more "direct" solution, but anyway it's a good workaround, thank you for it!

Comment: You are right, so sad to unable to help you this case. Regrettably the `mysqli` also can not help. Yeah I also spent some efforts when I tried to implement then I end up with that codes.