# execute a MySQL 'CREATE PROCEDURE' command from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I want to execute a `'CREATE PROCEDURE'` command from PHP. Is there a way to change the `MySQL DELIMITER` on a PHP connection? Of course, I know how to do it in a console session, but I want to do it from PHP. I want to be able to create stored procedures dynamically, and to do that I think I need to be able to reset the `DELIMITER from ;` to something else so that MySQL understands the semi-colons in my `'CREATE PROCEDURE'` definition is not the end of the whole statement.

I thought that I might be told this is a crazy thing to want to do (and I still might) but I have found this

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-mysqlscript-delimiter.html

which seems to be just what I'm looking for except that its for .NET not PHP.

Here's an example of the code I am generating and want to execute dynamically

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_update_1_8` (IN p_intClientID int(11) , IN p_8 varchar(30) ,OUT p_row_count INT )
BEGIN
UPDATE tblDriver_Audit SET q_8 = IFNULL(p_8, q_8), dtmLastChanged = NOW() WHERE intClientID = p_intClientID; 
SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO p_row_count; END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

If I put it all on one line I'm told it's a syntax error. If I try to put it into a prepared statement I get

`Error Code: 1295. This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`

I've also tried using multi-query but again there is a syntax error, and I've tried to execute the three "statements" separately (i.e. `DELIMITER-then-CREATE PROCEDURE-then-DELIMITER`).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Stored Procedures with PDO in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409755/create-stored-procedures-with-pdo-in-php)

Comment: Change `END;` to `END $$`.

Comment: thanks, Paul - quite right, have amended it, but I don't think it affects the question. About to try PDO

Comment: I just looked at my old code. I didn't change the `DELIMITER` and used something like `$pdo->exec($sql);`.

Comment: Yup, respect to Calimero, I can do it using PDO. I'd still like to know if I can set the DELIMITER on the connection though!

Comment: In that case, I'm afraid the answer is no, you can't keep the delimiter in there for php usage. Have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43708662/3120967