# Add MySql stored procedure via Propel

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, propel

I've some stored procedures in my DB. I had to do some change in all procedure therefore I thought I'll run once with propel.

How looks my code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_myprocedure;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_myprocedure(IN id INT(11), IN old JSON, IN new JSON)
...
```

What I've experienced that first SQL command exected successful but the second not! ...and I didn't get any sql error :(

When I run second sql command alone, I got this SQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$
```

I have to use *DELIMITER* because I have to use ';' inside the procedure.
If I run both SQL command in an Sql handler like Workbench...it works fine.

It is possible that Propel "doesn't like" *DELEMITER* word? Or not known it by Propel?

Has anyone ever met this mistake or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705396/how-to-create-a-stored-procedure-containing-a-delimiter-in-php-with-pdo

Comment: Tanks @YourCommonSense this suggestion. It was pretty interesting and finally I've resolved my problem with this article. I've prepared a parser for that. Thanks for your help!